Deterministic mapping on conditioned random variables
Suppose we have two random variables, $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$. And a determistic matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$ that is known, and $M$ may not be equal to $N$. My question is

Is $p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x}) = p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{Ax})$ correct?

If $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{0}$, we can see that $p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{Ax}) = p(\mathbf{y}) \neq p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})$ in general. However, what if the rows of $\mathbf{A}$ are orthogonal to each other which means we have $\mathbf{AA}^T = \mathbf{I}$?
If we use Bayes's rule, and get $p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{Ax}) = \frac{|det \mathbf{J}| p(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{y})p(\mathbf{y})}{|det \mathbf{J}|p(\mathbf{x})}$, so when $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible, we can assure the equality I stated before. But I cannot prove the case when $\mathbf{AA}^T = \mathbf{I}$.
